# Spice syntax in Altium for saving simulation data

Tags: ltspice, simulation, altium, spice

I want to save a maximum value from a simulation to a text/csv file (actually whatever that I can parse later).

I tried `.MEASURE` and `.SAVE`, but Altium doesn't generate any useful files (or at least I can't find them).

I have many resistors and I want calculate their derating and I don't want to do it manually. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why did you add the [tag:ltspice] and [tag:spice] tags?

Comment: because Altium use some spice syntax